# How to use open files after WinCRT spawn call

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, spawn, msvcrt

There is a `spawn*` function family in [WinCRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=msvc-170). The doc says that

> Files that are open when a _spawn call is made remain open in the new process.

I'm wondering how can I use open files after `spawn` call (except stdin/out/err). It seems like there are open file handles/descriptors which are available in a child process. How can a child recognize which descriptor to use? Should I pass any custom info in addition to `C_FILE_INFO`?

Comment: This (presumably) translates to the `bInheritHandles` being set to `TRUE` in the call to [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). The child process cannot (easily) discover the list of handles it inherited. It has to be told. Here's one way to do it: [Another way to create a process with attributes, maybe worse maybe better](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130426-00/?p=4543). You'll have to look into the code to figure out what the `spawn*` functions are really doing.